# mvc app requires fpexedll.dll?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've got an mvc4 app I've been developing, and I'm getting ready to deploy it.  In VS10, I had been developing it with a "Visual Studio Development Server", and, in order to take advantage of the publish package builder so that I can specify the install directory on the destination server, I need to convert the project to use a "Local IIS Web Server"

Problem is, when I make the change, and create the virtual directory, save, build, etc...upon actually loading the new site, I get the following error:

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
Calling LoadLibraryEx on ISAPI filter "C:\program files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\50\bin\fpexedll.dll" failed
Module........ IIS Web Core 
Notification.. Unknown 
Handler....... ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 
Error Code.... 0x8007007e
```

I can't imagine that I really need to add in front page extensions to the site (indeed, I've been told that this will not be allowed).  In my various searches, I'm not seeing that asp.net mvc apps require this, so I expect that I've just made some kind of braindead maneuver.

Can you suggest how I can get this running again?

Note: according to the error message, I should check that the path to the isapi dll is correct, and that web.config has good permissions, and logs, and such.  I've done all these and didn't find anything that *I* found to be out of whack, but that doesn't mean that I'm not still missing something obvious there...

Now, the `C:\program files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\50\bin\fpexedll.dll` file does not exist, but I don't want it to.  How can I get rid of the requirement for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dll is more than likely unnecessary.

Go into IIS 7.5, click on the Web Site in question.  Then, under the IIS grouping in the center of the dialog window, double click ISAPI Filters.

Delete the filter in question.

Boom!  Done.